# Freya security repositories turns to debian jessie

Tags: security, repositories

I encounter various problems with my computer. The first is that my native language is French and I don't know how to make this the default language, so the login screen, keyboard and the session are in English, the keyboard is in UK format.

Second small thing, I get errors in updates, like what `update-manager` was unable to download information for certain deposits and in addition, under the "Update" tab it provides me up update for Debian Jessie (see screenshot).

Third thing is that it does not want to launch Software Manager with an error:

```
home-PB @ home: ~ $ software-center 
ERROR: root: DebFileApplication import 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module> 
debfile from import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module> 
from softwarecenter.db.application Import Application, AppDetails 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module> 
import softwarecenter.distro 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 208, in <module> 
distro_instance = get_distro () 
File "/ usr / share / software-center / softwarecenter / distro / __ init_ .py", line 183, in get_distro 
module = import (distro_module_name, globals (), locals (), [], 1) 
ImportError: No named elementary os module 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/ usr / bin / software-center", line 128, in <module> 
softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import from SoftwareCenterAppGtk3 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 54, in <module> 
Import Application from softwarecenter.db.application 
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module> 
import softwarecenter.distro 
File "/ usr / share / software-center / softwarecenter / distro / __ init_ .py", line 208, in <module> 
distro_instance = get_distro () 
File "/ usr / share / software-center / softwarecenter / distro / __ init_ .py", line 183, in get_distro 
module = _import (distro_module_name, globals (), locals (), [], -1) 
ImportError: No Module named elementary os
```

Thank you in advance for your answer. I have two other old cuckoos which perfectly rotate them. I do not know what goes with it.

Good late night;)

[image: Screenshot]

Link to original : https://plus.google.com/u/0/109061274633620490063/posts/U3YdYfwtjrU

Translated with Google translate and a little bit of correcting

Comment: What did you do before this?

Comment: Just a fresh install and update/upgrade following the advices of http://itsfoss.com/things-todo-elementary-os-freya/ . Same behavior on a laptop I've just installed, duplicated source lists and security/jessie... Sorry I can't be more specific, and I'm noticed in the notification area that an error occurred during the update search.

Comment: Thanks Suici Doga for the translation, I did forget it as on the English platform that I was posting.

Comment: OK.I translated it with Google

Comment: I'm doing a another fresh install and I was wndering if the problem doesn't appear when you set system language and the system ask you to turn the names of the directories in the setted up language. Can not reproduce it, fed up with install, but this time I'll choose to keep the directories name in the original state and see what happens. Another symptom is that at the Grub boot menu, elementary was referred no more and replaced by Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: By the way, I did also check the files where the OS is defined and they all looks normal.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to fix it without reinstalling? If you did I'd be grateful if you could provide some advice. Also, and I know this is slightly off-topic, but what was the idiom that google translated as "two other old cuckoos which perfectly rotate them"? And what does it mean?

Comment: Same happened to me, solved with a fresh install WITHOUT INSTALLING ELEMENTARY TWEAKS, that appears to be the source of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Applications" in the top-right corners and type "Language", this find the "Language & Region" settings. Open this and it will allow selecting French language in the left panel.  This may require clicking "Unlock" in the top right (and entering your administrator or "sudo" password) or clicking an "install" button to complete installing missing languages. Hopefully once the system is configured in your language it will be easier to adjust update settings as you wish.

Rough Translation:

Cliquez sur "Applications" dans le coins en haut droite et tapez "Langue" , cette découverte les paramètres "Langue et Région". Ouvrez cela et il permettra la sélection de la langue française dans le panneau de gauche. Cela peut nécessiter en cliquant sur "Unlock" en haut à droite (et en entrant votre administrateur ou "sudo" mot de passe) ou en cliquant sur un bouton " installer " pour terminer l'installation de langues manquantes . Espérons une fois que le système est configuré dans votre langue , il sera plus facile de régler les paramètres de mise à jour que vous le souhaitez.

Comment: With the release of Elementary OS 0.4 Loki, a lot of effort has been put in by the developers towards features for an international audience and their own update/applications manager. Highly recommend this release, it should be much easier to configure languages in the GUI.